# How to manage the redirection in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I know there are plenty of similar questions like my, but I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

I think the issue is that am not getting the product.html and I assume that there is also a problem with the redirection to the product.html.

**product.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Product</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="product" action="/information" method="POST">
      <label for="product_id">Enter product ID: </label>
      <input id="product_id" name="product_id" type="text" required />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");

// load data
const products = require("./data.json");

const app = express();

// static files
app.use(express.static("public"));

// form middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/information", (req, res) => {
  // ES6 deconstruction syntax, get user input
  const { product_id } = req.body;

  // search product array
  const product = products.find((product) => product.Product_ID === product_id);
  if (product) res.json(product);
  else res.send("product not found");
});

// redirect all GET requests to product form
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/product.html");
});

app.listen(8000,console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:8000`));
```

When I run the code like above, I get the following error: *The page isn’t redirecting properly*

(Cookies & Cache is deleted). I even tried another project with a node.js server and the localhost in Firefox worked.

When I command the redirection out, I get this error: *Cannot GET /*

When I use "/" instead of "*" in the redirections, this error appears: *Cannot GET /product.html*

I don't understand why it doesn't get the product.html and why the redirection doesn't work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render product.html for every endpoint, you can use sendFile rather than redirect, you will need to use path module, which is a core module to resolve the path to html file:

```
 const path = require('path');
 //your code
 
 app.get('*', (req, res)=> {
      //note that product.html file is in the same directory or you specify    
      //its relative path
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'product.html'))
 })
```